# For loop to add column in multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, for-loop

Good evening,
I will start by saying I am very early in my coding journey.  Currently using a number of excel sheets from government data for a pandas project.   Each of these sheets represents a year.   I am attempting to add a column to each dataframe before I concat the entire list so I know which year the data came from at each point.  Currently, the code looks like this:

```
'''

df10 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2010_dl.xls')
df11 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2011_dl.xls')
df12 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2012_dl.xls')
df13 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2013_dl.xls')
df14 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2014_dl.xlsx')
df15 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2015_dl.xlsx')
df16 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2016_dl.xlsx')
df17 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2017_dl.xlsx')
df18 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2018_dl.xlsx')
df19 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m2019_dl.xlsx')
df10['Year'] = '2010'
df11['Year'] = '2011'
df12['Year'] = '2012'
df13['Year'] = '2013'
df14['Year'] = '2014'
df15['Year'] = '2015'
df16['Year'] = '2016'
df17['Year'] = '2017'
df18['Year'] = '2018'
df19['Year'] = '2019'

'''
```

However, I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this and was wondering if there might be a better way.  I originally attempted a For loop similar to this:

```
'''

for num in range(10,20):
  df+str(num)['Year'] = '20'+str(num)

'''
```

but I had no luck.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_dic = dict()

for n in range(10,20): #remember, the second number in range is exclusive
    year = f"20{n}"
    df = pd.read_excel(f'C:\Market research\national_m{year}_dl.xls')
    df["Year"] = year
    df_dic[year] = df
```

Comment: @roamingseaside no problem! please mark it as answered =]

Answer (score 0):

instead of using df10, df11,... you can use df[10], df[11],... which is make the code very easy.

```
for num in range(10,20):
  df[num] = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Market research\national_m20'+str(num)+'_dl.xlsx')
  df[num]['Year'] = '20'+str(num)
```